# How to fix the 'NameError' 'Person' not defined

Tags: python

I am getting the NameError anytime i create an instance/object from a class Person

i have created a class saved as Person.py
on the terminal i have imported everything using 'python -i'
i typed P1=Person("name","name",20)
but i got the following error

```
 python -i
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> p1=Person("i","j",20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

Code:

```
class Person:


    #constructor
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,age):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age

    #set first_name
    def setFirst_name(self,first_name):
        self.first_name = first_name

    #get first_name
    def getFirst_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    #set last_name
    def setLast_name(self,last_name):
        self.last_name = last_name

    #get last_name
    def getLast_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    #set age
    def setAge(self,age):
        self.age = age

    #get age
    def getAge(self):
        return self.age

    #get full_name
    def getFull_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    #get details
    def getDetails(self):
        details = {'First Name':self.first_name,'Last Name':self.last_name,'Age':self.age}
```

i expected P1 to create an object of Person so that when i call the function 'getDetails()' it should print the follow

First Name:i Last Name: j Age: 20

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://repl.it/repls/MammothOrneryOmnipage

Comment: If you are running this on the terminal you probably need to import your class: `from Person import Person`

Comment: Maybe you want to do `python -i the_file_containing_Person.py` instead of just `python -i`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to import a local file before you can use it - even if that file is in the same directory. This should work:

```
>>> import Person
```

But now, `Person` represents the contents of the file `Person.py`. To actually get to the `Person` class, you'll need to invoke it explicitly:

```
>>> p1 = Person.Person("i", "j", 20)
```

You can get around this by importing the *class* `Person` from the *file* `Person.py`:

```
>>> from Persion import Person
>>> p1 = Person("i", "j", 20)
```

Comment: Or they can do `python -i Person.py`. this will evalute `person.py` and start an interactive interpreter session with the class `Person` immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

So you're just running a python shell in the working directory where the `Person.py` file you wrote is located?

This isn't enough to tell the shell/Python that you want to use that file's content. Anything not already defined in that shell instance **must** be explicitly imported. (with correct capitalisation)

If you're working directly on the shell with `-i` then you must include arguments to go after that. Those being the file names you want, so your full line will be `python -i "Person.py"`.

If in future however you want to work in a script then this isn't possible and you'll need to specify *imports* in the "main" file you're working in and require your other files to be called to. 
e.g.

```py
#import ModuleName
# in this case your "module" is the "Person.py" file so:
import Person
```

This will then allow you to use the content of that "module"/file from the shell/script you're working in. To use your `Class` that is inside that module, which is also named "Person", you'll need to reference to it like `Person.Person(args)`

Of course that extra writing is going be annoying to look at so we can clean it up by importing *specifically* that Class as so:

```py
#from Module import Class
from Person import Person
# now we can just use Person(args) without having to specify the Person module every time
```

For future reference, as I assume you're learning about Classes:

If you have several classes inside a single module/file, say you added an `Animal` Class, then you can import them one by one, or all of them at once with an asterisk like so:

```py
#either
from Person import Person, Animal
#or
from Person import *
```